# To create new sheets after autofiler

Tags: excel, vba

As shown below, I made two different button which is one for RCEP and one for Other FTA. I gone through an error of run-time error '1004': Autofilter method of range class failed

This code is to copy the country selected to their assigned sheet

```
Sub FilteringOFTA()
 
Dim count_column, count_row As Integer
Dim extractws, to_ofta As Worksheet
Dim RowRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Worksheets("Extract").Activate

Set extractws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Extract")
Set to_ofta = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other FTA")

count_column = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight)))
count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)))

ActiveSheet.Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Array("MY", "SG", "MX", "CH", "IN"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

extractws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(count_row, count_column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
to_ofta.Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("Extract").ShowAllData
Worksheets("Extract").AutoFilterMode = False
Worksheets("Other FTA").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

```
Sub KRCNAutofilter()

Dim count_column, count_row As Integer
Dim fromextract, to_rcep As Worksheet
Dim RowRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Worksheets("Extract").Activate

Set fromextract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Extract")
Set to_rcep = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RCEP")

count_column = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight)))
count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)))

ActiveSheet.Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Array("CN", "KR"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

fromextract.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(count_row, count_column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
to_rcep.Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("Extract").ShowAllData
Worksheets("Extract").AutoFilterMode = False
Worksheets("RCEP").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

As I am new to Excel VBA i got overwhelmed with the codes I found. I tried to apply If, else and try to understand Lbound and Ubound but i could not grab the idea yet.

Comment: Is your data in a table instead of a normal range?

Comment: Are you on a Mac? `Range.Autofilter` is not supported on the Mac, create a table first and use `ListObject.Autofilter`

Comment: Also, please check whether you actually have 17 columns in the range to be filtered; using a field number higher than the number of columns will lead to this error. Use `Debug.Print count_column`

Comment: Hi, @Paul . I tried your method but I found an error, I do have 17 columns to be filtered. But worry not, I found the answer.

Comment: @Notus_Panda I am using normal range

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone while scrolling around thread. I found a thread from a forum that help me solved this problem and a little help from ChatGPT on helping to make the filtered array to go to the specific sheet.

[Link to the thread](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-using-code-to-filter-criteria-not-to-include-in-a-filter.536547/page-2#posts)

```
    Sub tryfilter()

    'Apply a filter; row 1 contains titles
    'Range("A1:Q1").Select
    'Selection.AutoFilter

    Dim filterCriteria() As String
    Dim count As Long, L As Long, rowNumb As Long
    Dim c As Variant, k As Variant
    Dim fromextract As Worksheet, to_rcep As Worksheet
    Dim count_column As Long, count_row As Long

    ' Set worksheets
    Set fromextract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Extract")
    Set to_rcep = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RCEP")

    ' Array of unwanted types
    Dim secondArray As Variant
    secondArray = Array("CN", "KR")

    ' Initialize variables
    count = 0
    rowNumb = fromextract.Range(fromextract.Range("A2"), fromextract.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.count

    For L = 2 To rowNumb + 1 ' Start from row 2
        c = fromextract.Cells(L, 1).Value
        If c <> k Then
            ' Check the current activity type against the array of unwanted types
            If UBound(Filter(secondArray, c)) = -1 Then
                ReDim Preserve filterCriteria(0 To count)
                filterCriteria(count) = c
                count = count + 1
            End If

            k = c
        End If
    Next L

    ' Apply filter
    With fromextract
        .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlToRight)).AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=secondArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        ' Find the last row and column with data
        count_row = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        count_column = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ' Copy visible cells
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(count_row, count_column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With

    ' Paste to target sheet
    to_rcep.Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Clear filter
    fromextract.AutoFilterMode = False

    ' Activate RCEP sheet
    to_rcep.Activate
    to_rcep.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Between "' Initialize variables" & "' Apply filter", there's an entire code you copied that is not used at all. You should define the range you want to autofilter on with the count_row/count_column, not define them after you use `.End(xlToRight)` which could give you a false range if there's a gap between the columns anyway.